# How to draw an image inside a circle?

Tags: c++, mfc, freeimage

I have a MFC application and i need to draw an image inside a circle (or crop the image in a circle).

I use FreeImage to load the image, so an answer using FreeImage or a MFC function will work.

This is how i load the image:

```
void DrawImage(CDC *pDC, RECT *pRect, const BYTE *pBuffer, int nBufferLength)
{
    FIMEMORY *pfmem = FreeImage_OpenMemory((BYTE*)pBuffer, nBufferLength);
    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FreeImage_GetFileTypeFromMemory(pfmem);
    FIBITMAP *pdib = FreeImage_LoadFromMemory(fif, pfmem);  

    sz.cx = FreeImage_GetWidth(pdib);
    sz.cy = FreeImage_GetHeight(pdib);

    CRect rc(pRect);

    BITMAPINFO *pbmpi = FreeImage_GetInfo(pdib);
    BYTE *pDibBits = FreeImage_GetBits(pdib);

    ::SetDIBitsToDevice(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 
                            rc.left, 
                            rc.top, 
                            rc.Width(), 
                            rc.Height(), 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            rc.Height(), 
                            pDibBits, 
                            pbmpi, 
                            DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    FreeImage_Unload(pdib);
    FreeImage_CloseMemory(pfmem);
}
```

Comment: [A Guide to WIN32 Clipping Regions](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/2095/a-guide-to-win-clipping-regions) and simply create an ellipse region ad select it as clip region  [CreateEllipticRgnIndirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183497(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Do you need any sort of anti-aliasing?

Comment: @IInspectable no, just crop the image in a circle.

Comment: Create a circular region and draw on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my answer in case someone runs in the same problem, it was quite easy actually just did what @Karthik Krish wrote:

```
//  Get the rect of a circle in the center o the image.
CRect rectMask(pRect);

int cx = rectMask.Width();
int cy = rectMask.Heigth();

if (cx > cy)
{
    rectMask.left += (cx - cy) / 2;
    rectMask.right = rectMask.left + cy;
}
else
{
    rectMask.top += (cy - cx) / 2;
    rectMask.bottom = rectMask.top + cx;
}

HRGN hRegiaoClip = NULL;

//  Create a region for the circle
hRegiaoClip = ::CreateEllipticRgnIndirect(&rectMask);

//  Select circle in the Device context.
::SelectClipRgn(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), hRegiaoClip);

//  Call function to draw the image (the one in the question).
DrawImage(pDC, pRect, pImgBytes, pSerial->GetImageBufferSize(), TRUE);

//  Clean up
::SelectClipRgn(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), NULL);
::DeleteObject(hRegiaoClip);
```